# How to add chapter names in header

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I like to add chapter names in my header. Currently I used this command

```
 \fancyhead[RO,LE]{Chapter \thechapter}
```

which can only show the chapter number . How can I add names instead of numbers.

Comment: Try `\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\leftmark}`. If that does not help, please show us a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/).

Comment: Do you mean adding the chapter  title?

Comment: Try this: Create \newcommand\myChapterTitle{}. At the beginning of each chapter, \renewcommand\myChapterTitle{whatever it is}. Then, in your heading, use \myChapterTitle instead of \thechapter.

Comment: yeah , \leftmark is working fine for me

Answer (score 1):

`\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\leftmark}` should do what you want.